# How to render large results on react frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I am using React frontend and express backend with PostgreSQL database. I want to render large json objects with approx. 8000 rows. Site works fine when there are less than 1000 records, but as number of records increase it becomes unable to render results. Json object is of the following format

```
[
  {
    book_name: "book 3",
    id: 21598,
    language: "urdu",
    main_cat: "cat1 ",
    media_link: [],
    pg_no: 18,
    riasat_ali_and_other: [],
    room: "None",
    search_cat: "poetry",
    sinf: "taranay",
    stage: "None",
    sub_cat: "taranay",
    tarzain: [],
    title: "book_title1",
    total: "1",
    video: [],
    written: ['link_to_img']
  },
  {
    book_name: "book 3",
    id: 21598,
    language: "urdu",
    main_cat: "cat1 ",
    media_link: [],
    pg_no: 18,
    riasat_ali_and_other: [],
    room: "None",
    search_cat: "poetry",
    sinf: "taranay",
    stage: "None",
    sub_cat: "taranay",
    tarzain: [],
    title: "book_title1",
    total: "1",
    video: [],
    written: ['link_to_img']
  }
]
```

QasaidPak is used to render results of DB to frontend, code is as follows

```
import { Grid,Card } from '@material-ui/core';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component, lazy } from 'react';
import './qasaid_pak.css'
const SearchHeader = lazy(() => import('../components/searchheader/Search.js'));
const QasidaMediaCard = lazy(() => import('../components/qasidamediacard'));

class QasaidPak extends Component{    
    state={
    searchinput:'',
    qasaid:[],
    issorted:false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // this.props.fetchQasaid()
        this.setState({resultStatus:'true'})
    };
    renderQasaid(){
        let i=0;
        let qasaid=[]
        if(this.state.issorted){
            qasaid=this.state.qasaid
            this.setState({issorted:false})
        }
        else{
            qasaid=this.props.qasaid
        }
        return qasaid.map((qaseeda) => {
            i+=1
            return(<QasidaMediaCard  key={qaseeda.id} id={i-1} qaseeda_pak={qaseeda}/>)})
    }
    GetSortOrder(prop) {    
        return function(a, b) {    
            if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {    
                return 1;    
            } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {    
                return -1;    
            }    
            return 0;    
        }    
    }
    sortPage=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('pg_no')),issorted:true})
        
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortSinf=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('sinf')),issorted:true})
        
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortSubcat=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('sub_cat')),issorted:true})
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortCat=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('main_cat')),issorted:true})
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortLang=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('language')),issorted:true})
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortTitle=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('title')),issorted:true})
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }
    sortBook=()=>{
        this.setState({qasaid:this.props.qasaid.sort(this.GetSortOrder('book_name')),issorted:true})
        // array.sort(GetSortOrder("Experience"))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                    <SearchHeader id='hidden-true'/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid xs={12} sm={12}>
                    <Card id="qasaid-header">
                        <Grid container className='row'>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.sortPage}>
                                <b>Written</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.sortSinf} >
                                <b>Sinf</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.sortSubcat}>
                                <b>Sub Category</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={2} sm={2} onClick={this.sortCat}>
                                <b>Main Category</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.sortLang}>
                                <b>Language</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={5} sm={5} onClick={this.sortTitle}>
                                <b>Title</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.sortBook}>
                                <b>Book</b>
                                <img src='https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/sort-alpha-down.svg' width='17px' height='17px'></img>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item id='poetry-results' xs={12} sm={12}>
                    {this.renderQasaid()}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    };
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    const {qasaid}=state
    console.log('Qasaid',qasaid)
    return {qasaid}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(QasaidPak);
```

Code for qasidamediacard is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import { AccordionSummary, Accordion,Container, Divider, Radio, AccordionDetails } from '@material-ui/core';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import { FormControlLabel,TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ImgsViewer from "react-images-viewer";

import './mediacard.css';
// import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube';
// import ReactPlayer from 'react-video-js-player';

import ReactWebMediaPlayer from 'react-web-media-player';
import { Media, Player } from 'react-media-player'
// const { PlayPause, MuteUnmute } = controls
class MediaCard extends Component{   
    render(){
        return(
            <Accordion className='root'>
                <AccordionSummary
                 expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                 aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                 id={(this.state.mediaLinkBool||
                    this.state.tarzainBool||
                    this.state.roomBool||
                    this.state.videoBool||
                    this.state.riasatAliBool||
                    this.state.stageBool)?"panel1a-header-data":"panel1a-header"}
                >
                    <Grid container>
                    <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1} onClick={this.pgClicked}>
                    <Link>
                        <b>{parseInt(this.state.qaseeda["pg_no"])}</b>
                    </Link>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid  item className='col' xs={1} sm={1}>
                        {this.state.qaseeda['sinf']}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1}>
                        {this.state.qaseeda['sub_cat']}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className='col' xs={2} sm={2}>
                        {this.state.qaseeda['main_cat']}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className='col' xs={1} sm={1}>
                        {this.state.qaseeda['language']}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid  item xs={4} sm={4}>
                            <b>{(this.state.qaseeda.search_cat!='book')?(
                                this.state.qaseeda["title"]
                            ):(
                                '...'+this.state.qaseeda["title"].split(' ').slice(0,12).join(' ')
                            )}</b>
                            
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className='col' xs={2} sm={2}>
                        {this.state.qaseeda['book_name']}
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    
                </AccordionSummary>
                <Divider></Divider>
                <AccordionDetails id={this.state.qaseeda.search_cat+'-details'}>
                {/* {this.state.qaseeda.search_cat!='book'} */}
                    {(this.state.qaseeda.search_cat!='book')?(
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid id="mediaPlayer" item xs={6} sm={6}>
                                {this.state.medialink &&
                                    <div>
                                        {this.state.isYoutubeLink &&
                                            <Media>
                                            <div className="media">
                                            <div className="media-player">
                                                <Player src={this.state.medialink}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="media-controls">
                                                {/* <PlayPause />
                                                <MuteUnmute /> */}
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Media>
                                        }
                                        {!this.state.isYoutubeLink &&
                                            <div>
                                                <ReactWebMediaPlayer
                                                title={this.state.qaseeda["title_qaseda_pak"]}
                                                audio={this.state.medialink} 
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </Grid> 
                            
                            <Grid item className='meta' xs={6} sm={6}>
                                    <RadioGroup className='radioGroup' value={this.state.version} onChange={this.handleVersionChange}>
                                        <Container className='radioGroup'>
                                            <FormControlLabel value='Tarzain' disabled ={(this.state.tarzainBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Tarzain" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value='MediaLink' disabled ={(this.state.mediaLinkBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Media Link" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value='RiasatAliAndOthers' disabled ={(this.state.riasatAliBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Riasat Ali And Others" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value='Video' disabled ={(this.state.videoBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Video" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value='RoomRec' disabled ={(this.state.roomBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Room" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value='StageRec' disabled ={(this.state.stageBool)?false:true} control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="Stage" />
                                            {this.state.isComboBoxEnabled}
                                        </Container>
                                        <Container className='comboBox'>
                                        {this.state.isComboBoxEnabled &&
                                        <Autocomplete
                                            className='combobox'
                                            value={this.state.selectedValue}
                                            onChange={this.comboBoxChange}
                                            options={this.state.displayValues}
                                            renderInput={(params) => <TextField placeholder="Click to select more audio / video" {...params} variant="outlined" />}
                                            />
                                        }
                                        </Container>  
                                    </RadioGroup> 
                            </Grid>
                            
                        </Grid>

                    ):(
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                {this.state.qaseeda.title}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        

                    )

                    }
                    
                </AccordionDetails>
                <ImgsViewer
                    imgs={this.state.imgSet['imgs']}
                    currImg={1}
                    isOpen={this.state.viewerIsOpen}
                    onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
                    onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
                    onClose={()=>{
                        this.setState({viewerIsOpen:false})
                    }}
                />
            </Accordion>
        )
    };
}
export default MediaCard;
```

Node app is working fine and is able to fetch data within few seconds but rendering records takes lots of time, can someone help me resolve this issue? Ideally, I want to be able to render all 8000 results and that within few seconds. Looking forward to your valuable suggestions. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

When you have such a big data, it is good to show that in parts. That means you can request data at once and show when needed on the view. You should use [react-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate).

```
npm install react-paginate --save
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

// Example items, to simulate fetching from another resources.
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

function Items({ currentItems }) {
  return (
    <>
      {currentItems &&
        currentItems.map((item) => (
          <div>
            <h3>Item #{item}</h3>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}

function PaginatedItems({ itemsPerPage }) {
  // We start with an empty list of items.
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(null);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch items from another resources.
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    console.log(`Loading items from ${itemOffset} to ${endOffset}`);
    setCurrentItems(items.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(items.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage]);

  // Invoke when user click to request another page.
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % items.length;
    console.log(
      `User requested page number ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
    );
    setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Items currentItems={currentItems} />
      <ReactPaginate
        breakLabel="..."
        nextLabel="next >"
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel="< previous"
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
      />
    </>
  );
}

// Add a <div id="container"> to your HTML to see the componend rendered.
ReactDOM.render(
  <PaginatedItems itemsPerPage={4} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

There might be other packages too, you can read its document [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate).